# setting the correct Android Build Target, minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, sdk, target

I have an app that actually was developed for level starting 7.
So far I had these settings:

```
Android Build Target = 7 - for compiling
minSdkVersion=7, targetSdkVersion=7 - for GooglePlay filter
```

Now as it turns out, when using these settings the app does not work correctly anymore on level 14 and above. While it does not crash, there are some functions which do not work correctly anmore.

Now I found out that changing the settings to this:

```
Android Build Target = 12, minSdkVersion=7, targetSdkVersion=7
```

solves the problem - AND the app can still be installed on level 7 devices and runs without problems.

Is it actually OK to leave the setting like that or are there any risks that I do not see?

It just seems strange that a level 12 compiled app just runs on level 7 (or hopefully on all others < 12) without any problems.

Many thanks!

Comment: which functions do not work with the first setting?

Comment: Actually this is not that easy to tell - the app is quite complicated and it seems that certain method calls are just not executed the same way as before. But I guess it does not really matter, as long as the suggested approach is valid and the app works. Ideally I do not want to search for the reason if the settings correct the problem without any drawback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config is OK as long as you've tested enough on Android API level 7 devices to be sure the app functions fine.

More normal might be to set the targetSdkVersion = Android Build Target

I have an app on the market (from 2010) with Android Build Target =4 and minSDKVersion=3 and it is fine. But I also set targetSdkVersion=4.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the documentation of the manifest.xml.
A few pointers :

targetsdkversion is used in order to tell to the framework for which version you have thought out your app. The best practice (and what google strongly recommends) is to set it to the last version (16 at the moment)

-minsdkversion is the minimum version of Android of which your app is able to run. Since new apis are added with each new version and that old version of Android are irrelevant, it is pretty useful.

-Never use maxsdkversion. It was useful when tablets where new in order to do give you some time to develop a tablet version of your app but it should be not be used anymore.

so yeah, target=min=7 is in fact the odd configuration.